# Attribute vs Static Property

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a model that needs to be saved in to a MongoDB collection. To get the collection name I have two options before me.

**1) Attribute**

I decorate the class with a custom attribute and use reflection to access the value inside it. I can then cache this with the `type` to avoid future lookups.

```
[MongoCollection("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
}
```

**2) Static Property**

Here I have a static property in the class that contains the collection name.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static string CollectionName { get { return "Foo"; } } 
}
```

I find that I am inclined to go with the former as it looks and feels cleaner but some of the senior devs here are turning their nose up at the use of reflection.

Is there a case to be made for the first option or is it just better to go with option 2?

Comment: First thought is, how will you filter classes if they arent flagged with Attributes? And imho.. If a Senior turns his nose up on unsage of an Attribute, he should prolly overthink his profession. Many mechanics in .net are based on reflection (for example MEF to name just one). Almost every useful extension like EntityFramework or NUnit work with reflection aswell. I would not recommend option 2

Comment: I agree with the first option being cleaner. Option three might be to use the same name for collection and class.

Comment: @ChriPf I feel that this could make refactoring a bit of a nightmare. If the class name changes for some reason, the collection would have to be renamed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can think of one more option, use a fluent notation and have a separate mapping class(es) that are charged with the MongoDB to POCO mapping. This is similar to what EF does with code first. This allows complete decoupling and would result in your POCO class `Foo` not having any mapping code for MongeDB at all. This would be my preference. In lieu of that I would vote for Attributes (decorations). This is exactly why Attributes exist.

Comment: @DavidPilkington the `return "Foo";` can be replaced by `return this.GetType().Name;` so the refactoring problem disappears.

Comment: @lokusking I was thinking about this. Probably either ignore the operation or throw an exception. I know that in Sqlite you have to decorate your DTO's with table names but I would have to see how they handle that case.

Comment: @KevinWallis I think that you missed my point. If I have a class that is called `Foo`, it wills save to a collection called `Foo`. Then if that class is renamed later, then it will create a new collection and the other data is sitting in the old collection.

Comment: What's the use case here? If all you're starting with is (say) a type or set of types, you cannot access the static property without using reflection either.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No you would have an instance of the type that you are trying to save.

Comment: @DavidPilkington - but what's the declared type of the variable containing the reference?

Comment: @DavidPilkington I think the attribute approach is good - the accepted answer hits the point there I guess. Entity Framework however _does_ use this very classname==tablename convention (which can be changed, but is the default) so I thought it is worth being mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a clear case of metadata vs. data:

- Option 1: Attributes *are supposed to* hold **metadata** about the entities they are attached to.
- Option 2: member fields and properties, regardless if instance or static, *are supposed to* hold **data** that make up the integral value of the class.

Hence, option 1, attributes, is the right approach to represent metadata. Usage of reflection is a mere technicality and can be encapsulated into a separate class, e.g. an `AttributeManager`, that would ease access to metadata and cache them appropriately to avoid performance overhead (should that be an issue in a particular case).

Comment: This was my plan. I have a manager class that has the cache within. There seems to be a sentiment that reflection is slow and should be avoided. Even if existing frameworks use it, "they know how to use it properly" ...

Comment: I will probably go ahead with the attributes and get ready to fight the case in a code review.

Comment: @DavidPilkington Yes, it actually is 'slow' in cases where you need to do millions of attribute lookups. In such a case a simple cache makes the problem disappear. A possible advantage of a full cached aproach is the ability to 'add' attributes on run-time. This may be useful in certain scenarios.

Comment: @DavidPilkington the [.NET Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab31zeh(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically says if you are worried about the speed of attribute lookups, you can consider **sealing** your custom attribute class.